# How to share SASS styles between libs inside my NX monorepo?

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, nomachine-nx

I'm trying to build a component library for angular and react. That's why I want to use the same styles(sass) for both libs.  I created a separate folder for my styles and included my main sass inside the component. but when I try to make a test npm build and tried to use inside an angular project I paced this problem [image]

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

as found in [this](https://dev.to/vitorstick/sharing-styles-between-apps-inside-nx-workspace-20i5) blogpost.

create a lib for styles

```
nx generate @nrwl/angular:library ui
```

The problem now, is the @import in all the scss files.
How to make them recognize the correct files?
On angular.json on every project the path will have to be included.

```
"projects": {
    "ds-project": {
        "projectType": "application",
        ...
        "architect": {
            "build": {
                ...
                "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                    "includePaths": [ "libs/ui/src/lib/styles" ]
                },
                "extractCss": true,
                ...
```

Now you can import the mixins on the scss files of your project just like if they were still part of the project:

```
@import "mixins/list_mixin";
@import "variables";

@include list_layout;
```

Even the base style, like font-family are importable.

Inside the style.scss of the project to became the global styles (for this case the module contains the global styles).

```
// styles.scss
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@import 'module';
```

Comment: though it can build but IDEs won't recognise it in the lib scss.

Answer (score -1):

Import the files with a path relative to the workspace root:

```
@import "libs/your-lib/src/styles/whatever"
```